# How to retrieve SET of objects from MAP

Tags: java, dictionary, tree

Little unsure of how to get to number of edges from the Nodes produced.

```
private TreeMap<Node, Set<Node>> nodeToNeighbours;
```

Add Edge Class

```
public void addEdge(Node node1, Node node2) {

nodeToNeighbours.put(node2, new TreeSet<Node>());
nodeToNeighbours.put(node1, new TreeSet<Node>());
}
```

Here's were im stuck. Would I have to cast?

```
public int getNumEdges() {
    //TreeSet<Node> x = new nodeToNeighbours.get(node1);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: What `getNumEdges()` supposed to return ? Is it size ?

Comment: Yes. An Integer to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the size of the map(how many object are mapped) Try :

```
public int getNumEdges() {
int x=nodeToNeighbours.size();
return x;
}
```

If you want the collection of object that are mapped in the Map

```
nodeToNeighbours.values();
```

You can also get the size from the collection of values

```
Collection<Object> objectCollection=nodeToNeighbours.values();
int s=objectCollection.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeSet<Node> x = nodeToNeighbours.get(node1);
```

This will give you the TreeSet value for the key node1.

calling x.getSize()  will give you the number of edges for that node assuming that you have registered all edges for the node in the tree set before adding it to nodeToNeighbours using node1 as a key.

I think what you might be looking for is...

```
public Integer getNumEdges() {
  final TreeSet<Node> x = nodeToNeighbours.get(node1);
  return x.getSize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are suppose to get `size` of your `TreeMap` then use something like this.

```
public int getNumEdges() {
    return nodeToNeighbours.size();
}
```

It will give you size of your `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get number of edge nodes using below code

```
public int getNumEdges() {
    int numberOfEdges = 0;
    if(nodeToNeighbours != null) {
        for(Set<Node> values : nodeToNeighbours.values()) {
            numberOfEdges = numberOfEdges + values.size();
        }
    }
    return numberOfEdges;
}
```

Comment: This will give the amount of nodes-edges in the entire map is this what is required or is the returned amount supposed to be how many edges are for a specific node. <-- Question is directed to User2077348

Comment: Entire Map  
Example 1--2--3.
Numbers = Nodes. -- = edges. 3 Nodes, 2 Edges